# How to read in only rows with specific values on a specific column?

Tags: python

This is a general question. Suppose I have a huge csv file, with a column `X` in it. Is there any way to read in only the rows whose values on column `X` is in the list `l= ['A' , 'C', 'Y']`?

For memory efficiency reasons, I would rather do this than read in the whole data and then subset.

Note: This question is not a duplicate as suggested. This question explicitly is about reading specific "rows" while the allegedly duplicate question is about reading specific "columns." Please pay closer attention before flagging a question as duplicate.

Comment: Read line by line and only keep the ones you are interested in?

Comment: I'd use `csv.DictReader`, then `for line in dr` `if line['X'] in l: #do something`